# Span a Gradient on several Rectangle

Tags: qml

I want a single `LinearGradient` to be used as the background, spanned into several sibling `Rectangle`s. In each `Rectangle`, you can see a different part of the gradient.
I use an `OpacityMask` to « fill » the `Rectangle`s with the gradient.
The `LinearGradient` `width` is the sum of each `Rectangle` `width`.

If I use a single `Rectangle`, it works. Beginning with two, it does not behave correctly, whatever I try (I leave bits in the code below to imagine). The best result I had so far is having the same part of the `LinearGradient` repeated in each `Rectangle`.
I guess I could use one `LinearGradient` per `Rectangle`, changing the `GradientStop` values, but it looks complicated and I guess there is a simple an elegant solution.

```qml
    Rectangle
    {
        id: page1
//        anchors.fill: parent

//            id: masqCont
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            border.color: "blue"
            width: childrenRect.width
            height: childrenRect.height
            visible: false

            Rectangle
            {
                id: masq1
                y:0
                border.color: "red"
                border.width: 10
                width: 100
                height: 100
                radius: 40
                Text {text: "Un"}
                visible: true
            }
            Rectangle
            {
                x:width
                id: masq2
                border.color: "red"
                border.width: 10
                width: 100
                height: 100
                radius: 40
                Text {text: "deux"}
                Text {text: "deux"}
                visible: true
            }
    }

            LinearGradient {
                id:grad
                width: 200 //masqCont.childrenRect.width
                height: 100//masqCont.childrenRect.height

                //anchors.fill: masqCont
                start: Qt.point(0, 0)
                end: Qt.point(200,100)//masqCont.width, masqCont.height)
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "white" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "black" }
                }
                visible: false
            }
            OpacityMask {
                id: om21
                anchors.fill: page1;
                source: grad
                maskSource: page1;
            }
//            OpacityMask {
//                id: om21
//                anchors.fill: masq1;
//                source: grad
//                maskSource: masq1;
//            }
//            OpacityMask {
//                id: om22
//                anchors.fill: masq2;
//                source: grad
//                maskSource: masq2;
//            }
  //      }

//    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

The major problem is you chose a white Rectangle as a container for your child rectangles. This causes the entire LinearGradient to be displayed, as the mask is fully opaque (no alpha).

See below for a working example (you can move the rectangles by dragging them)

```qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 400

    Item
    {
        id: page1
        anchors.fill: parent
        opacity: 0
        Repeater
        {
            model: 20
            Rectangle
            {
                id: masq1
                x:Math.random()*(page1.width-width)
                y:Math.random()*(page1.height-height)
                width: 50
                height: 50
                radius: 5

                MouseArea
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag.target: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }

    LinearGradient {
        id:grad
        anchors.fill: page1
        start: Qt.point(0, 0)
        end: Qt.point(page1.width, 0)
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "white" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "black" }
        }
        visible: false
    }

    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: page1;
        source: grad
        maskSource: page1;
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I expect this kind of code to be written very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just `Rectangle`s you want, `OpacityMask` is an overkill.
You might just use a `ShaderEffectSource` instead.

You set the `soruceItem` to be your gradient, and then select the `sourceRect` to be equal to you `Rectangle`. You might need to use `map[From/To]Item` to map the coordinates correctly.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: win
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: grad
        anchors.fill: parent
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0; color: 'blue' }
            GradientStop { position: 0.33; color: 'red' }
            GradientStop { position: 0.66; color: 'yellow' }
            GradientStop { position: 1; color: 'blue' }
        }

        visible: false
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        sourceItem: grad
        x: 50
        y: 50
        height: 100
        width: 200
        sourceRect: Qt.rect(x, y, width, height)
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        sourceItem: grad
        x: 280
        y: 80
        height: 150
        width: 70
        sourceRect: Qt.rect(x, y, width, height)
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a nice piece of code, but it does not allow, in this version, the Rectangle to be rounded (radius is used)